# Which chapter of the manga version of Hyouka corresponds to the last episode of anime?

Tags: hyouka

Is Hyouka manga still ongoing? Which chapter of the manga version of Hyouka corresponds to the last episode of anime?

Answer (score 1):

As of 26 October 2017, the manga consisted of 11 volumes and was still on-going.

Regarding the corresponding chapter to the last episode of the anime (episode 22: "The Hina Doll that Took a Detour"), as of February 2018, the answer is ***not yet***, but possibly will be in volume 12.

---

As a matter of fact, *Hyouka* is originally a light novel series. Both the anime and the manga were based on it.

For reference, these are the current 6 volumes of the light novel (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hy%C5%8Dka#Novels)):

1. *Hyōka*
2. *Closing Credits of the Fool*
3. *The Order of Kudryavka*
4. *The Hina Doll that Took a Detour* (compilation of short stories)
5. *The Approximation of the Distance of Two*
6. *Even Though I'm Told I Now Have Wings* (compilation of short stories)

The anime's order (from [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%80%88%E5%8F%A4%E5%85%B8%E9%83%A8%E3%80%89%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA#%E5%90%84%E8%A9%B1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88)):

- Episode 1:

  - Part A: *Hyōka* (1)
  - Part B: *The Hina Doll that Took a Detour* (4)
- Episode 2-5: *Hyōka* (1)
- Episode 6-7: *The Hina Doll that Took a Detour* (4)
- Episode 8-11: *Closing Credits of the Fool* (2)
- Episode 11.5 (OVA): anime original story
- Episode 12-17: *The Order of Kudryavka* (3)
- Episode 18: *Even Though I'm Told I Now Have Wings* (6)
- Episode 19-22: *The Hina Doll that Took a Detour* (4)

And for the manga (from [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%80%88%E5%8F%A4%E5%85%B8%E9%83%A8%E3%80%89%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA#%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB)):

- Volume 1: *Hyōka* (1), *The Hina Doll that Took a Detour* (4)
- Volume 2: *Hyōka* (1), *The Hina Doll that Took a Detour* (4)
- Volume 3: *Hyōka* (1), *The Hina Doll that Took a Detour* (4), *Closing Credits of the Fool* (2)
- Volume 4-5: *Closing Credits of the Fool* (2)
- Volume 6: Anime ch. 11.5 (OVA), *The Order of Kudryavka* (3)
- Volume 7-9: *The Order of Kudryavka* (3)
- Volume 10: *The Order of Kudryavka* (3), *Even Though I'm Told I Now Have Wings* (6), *The Hina Doll that Took a Detour* (4)
- Volume 11: *The Hina Doll that Took a Detour* (4)

---

For comparison, volume 11 consists of:

- Chapter 43: Christmas in the Box
- Chapter 44: Sappy New Year (1)
- Chapter 45: Sappy New Year (2)
- Chapter 46: The Homemade Chocolates Case

and the last 4 episodes (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hy%C5%8Dka#Episode_list)) are:

- Episode 19: Anyone Who Knows
- Episode 20: Sappy New Year
- Episode 21: The Homemade Chocolates Case
- Episode 22: The Hina Doll that Took a Detour